# обработка DBNull с помощью рефлексии

Tags: c#

Есть такой код, который перекидывает поля с одинаковыми названиями с 2-х разнотипных объектов.

```
  private void SetIsNotNull<T, V>(ref T a, V from, string propName)
        {
            object tempObj = from.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(from, null);

            if (tempObj != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var prop = a.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
                    Type pr = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
                    if (pr == typeof(string))
                        a.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(a, tempObj.ToString(), null);
                    else if (pr == typeof(double))
                        a.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(a, double.Parse(tempObj.ToString()), null);
                    else
                        a.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(a, tempObj, null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

        }
        private void SetIsNotNull<T, V>(ref T a, V from)
        {
            var aProps = a.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
            var fromProps = from.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
            foreach (string propName in fromProps)
            {
                if (aProps.Contains(propName))
                {
                    SetIsNotNull<T, V>(ref a, from, propName);
                }

            }

        }
```

Всё ок работало, пока не попытался перекинуть таблицу из xsd схемы. Вылетает исключение
"Значение для столбца 'DATE_N' в таблице 'LPUAcnt' равно DBNull."
Я знаю что это можно решить изменив поведение в xsd конструкторе, но вот что выходит при попытке изменить
[image: Ошибка]

Также для каждой ячейки есть метод IsColumnNull(), но как его вызвать в моём коде, подскажите?